# Handle Bluetooth(classic) Pairing Unpairing requests in UWP

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, iot, pairing

I'm trying to programmatically accept a Bluetooth pairing request from an Android device on a Win 10 iot. Which unfortunately has not worked yet. I can not hang in, on any event that gives me the opportunity to accept the pairing request of the android device!
The same goes for the unpairing.

I get the 
`ActivationKind.DevicePairing` via the `OnActivated (IActivatedEventArgs args)`
 However, I can't find data in der to accept the pairing.

[pairing process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jpTD.png)

In the examples I have seen so far, the pairing starts allways from a win 10 iot device, which works! But I need it the opposite way.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

For Windows IoT Core device you can use [TryRegisterForAllInboundPairingRequests()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformationpairing) to enable you to app receive pairing request.

As for example code you can reference official sample: [IoTCoreDefaultApp->Settings.xaml.cs](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/blob/develop/IoTCoreDefaultApp/IoTCoreDefaultApp/Views/Settings.xaml.cs).

Comment: You can see in IoTCoreDefaultApp-> Settings.xaml.cs.
on line 137 there you register the incoming pairing requests:
App.InboundPairingRequested += App_InboundPairingRequested;
And if the pairing event happens, you go to line 170:
private async void App_InboundPairingRequested(object sender, InboundPairingEventArgs inboundArgs)
and there is noting don with this request it only displays that a request was in coming.

Comment: For more detailed information you can reference [the same question on MSDN.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/523c1e11-dc91-4115-9785-8e91886104f9/pairing-bluetoothclassic-devices-programaticaly-on-win-10-iot-with-raspberry-pi-3?forum=WindowsIoT)